# How to write python code in a file in mininet

Tags: python, xterm, mininet

In mininet after entering `sudo dhclient eth1` and `ifconfig eth1` I can not access the xterm environment, even when I enter `xterm` in command line it answers "DISPLAY is not set", when I `enter DISPLAY=10.0 xterm` it answers that it can not open display 10. what should I do?

I am a beginner in mininet and I want to write python code in a file in mininet and I don't know where to write code because I just see command line and nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

To write python code in mininet you can use the mininet's python API.

I think what you're looking for is in this tutorial [Introduction to Mininet](https://github.com/mininet/mininet/wiki/Introduction-to-Mininet)

Comment: thank you very much. the problem was with the virtual machine I have downloaded. I just install ubuntu and install mininet through ubuntu terminal. there was no problem after that.